# Polymorphism with cython extesion types

Tags: cython

I have a cython extension type that I want to make more general. One of the attributes of this extension type is a `double` and I want it to be a memoryview (`double[::1]`) when needed.

Here is a simple example :

```py
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef class Test:

    cdef bint numeric
    cdef double du  

    def __init__(self, bint numeric):

        self.numeric = numeric

        if self.numeric:
            self.du = 1

        else:
            self.du = np.ones(10)

    def disp(self)
        print(self.du)

Test(True).disp()   # returns 1
Test(False).disp()  # gives of course an error
```

I tried to subclass `Test` changing `du` type to `double[::1]` and implementing a new `__init__` but it seems that we can't override class attributes of extension types. Even if it worked, it wouldn't be satisfactory because I don't really want to have one extension type for each case.

The best would be that my extension type directly handle both cases (scalar `du` and memoryview `du`).

Is there a way to do this with Cython ?

Comment: Have you considered just using a length 1 array?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use fused_type as attributes type. You can have two options here:

You could try to use the memory adress of the variable you want to call, and cast it when needed (everything is explained [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html#selecting-specializations).) Unfortunately, I did not succeed at making it work with typed memory views.

Or you can use your defined attribute numeric to call the appropriate method:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef class Test:

    cdef bint numeric
    cdef double du_numeric
    cdef double[:] du_mem_view

    def __init__(self, bint numeric):

        self.numeric = numeric

        if self.numeric:
            self.du_numeric = 1

        else:
            self.du_mem_view = np.ones(10)

    def disp(self):
        if self.numeric:
            print(self.du_numeric)
        else:
            print(self.du_numeric_mem_view)

Test(True).disp()   # returns 1
Test(False).disp()  # Does not give an error anymore !
```

Comment: Sure, this is an option. But I wanted to avoid this because I use `du` in about 25 methods in each extension type !

Comment: I see your point, but even using fused tpye will be super hard as you need to deferenece the pointer twice if it is an array :s. If you have any other workaround, let me know I am curious ! :) Good luck